# Running octave function prints lines of command name

Tags: emacs, octave

Basically I'm running Octave 4.2.1 in Emacs 25.2.1 all within iTerm2 on macOS Sierra and every time I run a function (any function), a list of what look like command names is printed before the answer. I have tried to look up to see if this has been answered, but I'm having trouble describing the output list in a search. Here is the function command:

```
octave> f(3)
```

where f is declared as:

```
octave> function y = f(x)
>y = x + 10;
>endfunction
```

and the output is:

```
yes_or_no
ylabel
ylim
yulewalker
x
xlabel
xlim
xor
end
end_try_catch
end_unwind_protect
endfor
endfunction
endgrent
endif
endparfor
endpwent
endswitch
endwhile
endfunction
endfunction
ans =  13
```

I have tried placing semicolons at the end of every line (because I was unsure if this is function output that could be silenced with a semicolon), but that didn't pan out.

Edit: I have also tried turning off diary because I'm not sure that diary is. Needless to say, did not work out.

Let me know what I can do to stop this output. And if this is a duplicate due to me not having the vocabulary to search for my solution, obviously just mark it and I'll follow the link.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you probably have an `echo on all` command somewhere on your start-up script or the script you're running or something. Type `echo off all` in the console and run your script again to see if it goes. If it does, it's probably included in the script you're running, otherwise it may be an octave startup script (or even an emacs preference)

Comment: Yeah I've tried toggling echo off but its not really echo output. Thanks for the suggestion though.